# Extrea backslash added to n when parsing a string from XML

Tags: c++, xml, string

I read an xml data into C++ application.Some of the data is multiline string.Each new line is broken by '\n' escape character.But when it is loaded into the program the backslash n gets extra backslash from the left.For example:

**In XML:**

```
<node  attrStr = "Hello!\nWhat's your name?"  />
```

**In the program:**

```
"Hello!\\nWhat's your name?"
```

So it causes '\' and 'n' to become separate characters.
It doesn't happen if the string is hardcoded into the program source code.
How this issue can be solved?

Important to note that the XML string is read into std::wstring to take care of unicode characters.

Found the answer [here](http://ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=49332).

Replacing '\n' with  `&#10;` inside XML solves the issue.

Comment: What are you using to parse the XML?

Comment: Is your XML parser expected to xform a C/C++ escape sequence for you? If not, how about replacing "\\n" with "\n" in your C++ code after attribute value extraction and call it good? Or enable whatever feature is supposed to do this for you in your XML parser (whatever that is).

Comment: I don't want to do filtering during runtime as my app is low latency.I use pugixml,but I also found the solution :  http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=49332

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to escape a newline character in XML you will have to use the entity `&#10;`. So the correct XML would look like:

```
<node attrStr = "Hello!&#10;What's your name?" />
```

Since XML does not allow character escaping with backslash the string "\n" is read as two normal characters '\' and 'n'.
If you want to load the XML content with correct line breaks, you must replace the "\n" parts with  "
" as suggested in the answer proposed by @Angew.

Alternatively, you could also modify or pre-process the XML file before reading it.

Answer (score 2):

The two characters `\` and `n` after each other do not *inherently* have any special meaning. In *some* contexts, these two characters are used to encode a newline. String literals in C++ source files *are* such a context. XML files are *not* such a context.

This means that when parsing an XML file containing the substring `\n`, you will get a string containing the substring `\n` in the memory of your C++ program. Anything else would be wrong. If you want `\n` in your data to represent a newline, you have to use string substitution once the data is in memory.

After parsing the string, simply replace each `\n` occurence with a the ASCII character LF and you're set. This is how you could do it (inefficiently) with the standard library:

```
std::string s = getTheStringFromXml();
for (size_t idx = 0;;)
{
  idx = s.find("\\n", idx);
  if (idx == s.npos)
    break;
  s[idx] = '\n';
  s.erase(idx + 1);
}
```

Comment: While your answer is correct,I can not allow this solution in my application which is real time and the low latency is of primary considerations.I can't spend time running over  sometimes very long strings and filtering them.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs also in JavaScript, and the fix
`&#10;` works well